# Elementary proof of Bott periodicity

Tags: vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

The elementary proof of Bott periodicity was found by Atiyah and Bott, and published in the paper "[On the periodicity theorem for complex vector bundles](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/abott3.pdf)". In [Hatcher's book](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) p.41-51, this elementary proof is called the fundamental product theorem. One thing I don't understand is why, in Hatcher's book, it takes so much to write about convergence issues (even $\epsilon-\delta$ shows up) to show that every clutching function can be approximated by a Laurent polynomial, while in Atiyah and Bott's paper, I don't think any convergence issue is mentioned. I have only read Hatcher's book and I think that step is necessary, so I was wondering why this issue isn't addressed in the Atiyah-Bott paper or how it is bypassed.